# How to get only the selected user's information

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, tableview

how can i make it so that when a user is selected only that users information is loaded in the next view?
im having trouble passing the pfuser to the next view.

for instance :

cell 1 is for user 1; if selected user 1's information will be shown in another view,

cell 2 is for user 2; if selected user 2's information will be shown in another view,

and so on.

ver similar to instagram, how you tap the image or username and it shows you only their pictures.

currently i have this in the second views .m file, its written to show the current users info not the selected users as it is equal to [PFUser currentUser];

basically i want it dynamic to what user is chosen, there info is shown.

```
// querying photos
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
        return nil;
    }


    PFQuery *photosFromCurrentUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:@"userTookPhoto" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *superQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:photosFromCurrentUserQuery,nil]];
    [superQuery includeKey:@"userTookPhoto"];
    [superQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    return superQuery;

}
```

Comment: Do you use "UIView" or "UIViewController" for transition between two? @farhan

Comment: @MilanKamilya its between two UIViewControllers, with a push segue to get to the second view.

Answer (score 0):

Write a public method, named "setRequiredObject:(NSString:)str;" to Second View Controller and assign the received object to any global object in that method.

```
-(void)setRequiredObject:(NSString*)str{
   object = str;
}
```

Add following code to First View Controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

   NSLog(@"prepare for segue");
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"agendaAgendaSegue"]) {

       if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setRequiredObject:)]) {

            [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setRequiredObject:) withObject:object];

        }

   }
}
```

Please share if you still getting problems.

Comment: okay so in my code do you see where it says :

PFQuery *photosFromCurrentUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [photosFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:@"userTookPhoto" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

instead of equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]; i need to make it equal the user selected in the previous view. do you get that?

Comment: Then set the object through prepareForSegue and you will get that object in next viewController and replace that object with [RFUser currentUser].

Comment: so replace [pfuser currentuser] with the object i pass from prepareForSegue